# Impossible to delete a project in Sonarqube (From UI or with API)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web

I want to delete big projects (Millions of LOC) in my Sonarqube instance (Version 6.7.5).
The problem with some projects is when I do a deletion action (From the UI or with API), it doesn't complete the deletion (I continue to see the project in the UI).
When I retry (either from UI or API), i got the same error message "****Couldn't find root component with uuid** XXXXX**"

[image]

Have you an ideo on how completely delete this project ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://community.sonarsource.com/t/analysis-failing-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-couldnt-find-root-component-with-uuid-abcd/16883/9

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't upgrade to recents versions due to software obsolescences

Comment: Seems like a database inconsistency issue https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sq-7-9lts-couldnt-find-root-component-with-uuid-xyz/28432/7. Although I'm not sure how to fix it. Maybe ask Sonarqube folks?